# Can't create Linq to Sql file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create DataContext.dbml file but for some reason I don't have such an option. I have Linq to Sql tools installed in Visual Stusio, but it makes no difference. Is there something else I need?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCa00.png)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I created a wrong project type. I had to use .Net type of winforms app